# Fetch attachments from gmail using imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to fetch attachments from my gmail account.

Code is

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'chrisvoges@gmail.com';
$password = 'abcdefghi';
$inbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", 
$username, $password, NULL, 1,array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN')) or 
die(var_dump(imap_errors()));
```

I have also allowed imap via gmail settings

**Error**

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(107) "[ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)" [1]=> string(23) "Too many login failures" }
```

Whats wrong. Moreover does this process requires ssl certificate?

Comment: Did you try and follow the error message / link in the error message?

Comment: First you have to give a permission to access account  go to  following link :  [link](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Comment: @Epodax it redirects to help page. I have tried some solution from there too might nothing worked

Comment: @nu1_ww, I have tried this too, didn't work

Comment: Have you enabled "less secure apps"?

Comment: @Max yes I have enabled less secure apps

Comment: Changing the password of the account to a more stronger password worked.